# How to mask input box with real-time currency as per user locale in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, locale, currency-pipe

I need a locale dynamic input currency mask as user types it formats itself adding symbol and commas example($1,111) as per user locale navigator.language() or currencypipe, I got [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular11-currency-mask?file=app%2Fcurrency-mask.directive.ts)  how can I modify this first input box code to get that.

can you provide the code...